# Costandard filtrations of indecomposable tilting objects

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, representation-theory, homological-algebra, abelian-categories

*Setting*
Let $\mathsf{C}$ be a locally finite abelian category. Assume that there exists a poset $\Lambda$ and a complete set $\{L(\lambda)\}_{\lambda \in \Lambda}$ of representatives of isomorphism classes of simple objects of $\mathsf{C}$. Choose such a set $\Lambda$ and a corresponding set $\{L(\lambda)\}_{\lambda \in \Lambda}$.

We call $\nabla(\lambda)$ a *costandard object* for $L(\lambda)$ if $\operatorname{Soc}\nabla(\lambda)\cong L(\lambda)$ and all composition factors $L(\mu)$  of $\nabla(\lambda)/\operatorname{Soc}\nabla(\lambda)$ satisfy $\mu < \lambda$. Here, $\operatorname{Soc}\nabla(\lambda)$ denotes the socle of $\nabla(\lambda)$.

We call $\Delta(\lambda)$ a *standard object* for $L(\lambda)$ if $\operatorname{Hd}\Delta(\lambda)\cong L(\lambda)$ and all composition factors $L(\mu)$  of $\operatorname{Rad}\Delta(\lambda)$ satisfy $\mu < \lambda$. Here, $\operatorname{Hd}\Delta(\lambda)$ denotes the head of $\Delta(\lambda)$ and $\operatorname{Rad}\Delta(\lambda)$ denotes the radical of $\Delta(\lambda)$.

We say that an object $N \in \mathsf{C}$ has a *costandard filtration* if there exists a filtration
$$0=N_0 \subsetneq N_1 \subsetneq … \subsetneq N_{n-1} \subsetneq N_n=N$$ by subobjects $N_i$ of $N$ such that for each $i$ the quotient $N_i/N_{i-1}$ is isomorphic to a costandard object $\nabla(\lambda_i)$, for some $\lambda_i \in \Lambda$. Dually, we define a *standard filtration*.

*Question*
Let now $\mathsf{C}$ be a standard category as defined in the paper [CELLULARITY OF ENDOMORPHISM ALGEBRAS OF TILTING OBJECTS](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2107.07887.pdf) .
By assumption there exists an epimorphism $\pi^\lambda:T(\lambda)\twoheadrightarrow \nabla(\lambda)$. It is claimed in the proof of Lemma 3.1 (page 15) that $\nabla(\lambda)$ occurs at the top of a costandard filtration of $T(\lambda)$. Why?

*What I can think of …*
By definition $T(\lambda)$ admits a costandard filtration
$$0=N_0\subsetneq\cdots\subsetneq N_{n-1}\subsetneq N_n=T(\lambda)$$
By definition there exists $\lambda_i \in \Lambda$ such that $N_n/N_{n-1}\cong \nabla(\lambda_i)$. But why does $\lambda=\lambda_i$ hold? I tried to use that $T(\lambda)$ is of highest weight $\lambda$ or equivalently Remark 2.15 of aforementioned paper. However, I do not know how to do so.

*EDIT*
In their paper ['Highest weight theory for finite- dimensional graded algebras with triangular decomposition'](http://eprints.gla.ac.uk/159273/7/159273.pdf) Bellamy and Thiel again make this claim in the context of highest weight categories. They write on page 19:

> If $M$ admits a standard filtration and has highest or lowest weight $\lambda$, we cannot locate where $\Delta(\lambda)$ occurs in a standard filtration. But if $\operatorname{Hd}(M)\cong L(\lambda)$, then $\Delta(\lambda)$ must occur at the top of any standard filtration. Similarly if $M$ admits a standard filtration and has highest or lowest weight $\lambda$ and $\operatorname{Soc}(M)\cong L(\lambda)$, then $\nabla(\lambda)$ must occur at the bottom of any costandard filtration.

On the same page they further claim:

> We note if $M$ has highest weight $\lambda$, then $L(\lambda)$ can occur anywhere in a composition series of $M$. But if $\operatorname{Hd}(M) \cong L(\lambda)$, then this forces $L(\lambda)$ to occur at the top of any composition series.

Comment: So the idea is that you already have that module at the top, but you need to also show you can extend that to a costandard filtration.
I recall this being a bit more tricky than I expected, and I don't recall how to do it. I think it is proven for the special case where these are representations of a reductive algebraic group in Jantzens book, and it might be possible to mimic that proof (otherwise one might go to Donkin's original paper for the algebraic group picture, or some of the CPS papers).

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Thank you! Do you have a more precise reference by any chance? I could not find a proof of the result in Jantzen's book .

Comment: Donkin's paper is "On tilting modules for algebraic groups", Mathematische Zeitschrift (1993). Volume: 212.
I am not sure which CPS papers consider this. As I recall, the context they discuss it in is that the given conditions on the category are equivalent to it being the category of modules over a quasi-hereditary algebra.

Comment: Regarding the addition: Note that while the highest weight of the tilting module and the costandard module at its top coincide, this is generally not the highest weight of the head of either of them.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Yes, you are right. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By Lemma 2.11 of Bellamy and Thiel's paper, the length of a costandard filtration of $T(\lambda)$ is independent of the particular filtration we choose, so let's say this length is $n$, and let's assume that $t$ is maximal subject to the existence of a costandard filtration
$$0=N_0\subsetneq\cdots\subsetneq N_{n-1}\subsetneq N_n=T(\lambda)$$
of $T(\lambda)$ with $N_t/N_{t-1}\cong\nabla(\lambda)$. We want to prove $t=n$. If not, then $N_{t+1}/N_{t-1}$ has a two step filtration with factors $\nabla(\lambda)$ at the bottom and $\nabla(\mu)$, for some $\mu<\lambda$, at the top. By Lemma 2.9(4) of the paper, $\operatorname{Ext}^1\left(\nabla(\mu), \nabla(\lambda)\right)=0$, and so $N_{t+1}/N_{t-1}\cong\nabla(\lambda)\oplus\nabla(\mu)$, so we can change $N_t$ so that we have a new costandard filtration with $N_{t+1}/N_t\cong\nabla(\lambda)$, contradicting maximality of $t$.